# wxOwnerDrawnComboBox-inherited class is not focusable

Tags: wxwidgets

I have implemented an own combobox which is used as font-selector. To display what the selected fonts look like directly within the combobox, I created a new class FontStyleComboBox which inherits from wxOwnerDrawnComboBox. Following the full class is shown, only the font-management part is missing:

```
class FontStyleComboBox : public wxOwnerDrawnComboBox
{
private:
   std::vector<wxFont> m_fontList;

public:
   virtual void OnDrawItem(wxDC& dc,const wxRect& rect,int item,int flags) const
   {
      if (item == wxNOT_FOUND) return;
      wxCoord w1,h1,w2,h2;
      dc.GetTextExtent(GetString(item),&w1,&h1);
      dc.DrawText(GetString(item),
              rect.x + 3,
              (rect.y + 0) + (rect.height / 2) - (dc.GetCharHeight() / 2)
              );
      dc.SetFont(m_fontList[item]);
      dc.GetTextExtent(GetString(item),&w2,&h2);
      if (w2<250)
      {
         if (rect.x+10+w1>135)
          dc.DrawText(_T("AaBbCcDd 1234"),
                  rect.x+10+w1,
                  (rect.y + 0) + (rect.height / 2) - (dc.GetCharHeight() / 2)
                  );
         else
          dc.DrawText(_T("AaBbCcDd 1234"),
                  135,
                  (rect.y + 0) + (rect.height / 2) - (dc.GetCharHeight() / 2)
                  );
      }
   }

   virtual void OnDrawBackground(wxDC& dc, const wxRect& rect,int item, int flags) const
   {
      // If item is selected or even, or we are painting the
      // combo control itself, use the default rendering.
      if ((flags & (wxODCB_PAINTING_CONTROL | wxODCB_PAINTING_SELECTED)) ||
          (item & 1) == 0)
      {
         wxOwnerDrawnComboBox::OnDrawBackground(dc, rect, item, flags);
         return;
      }
      // Otherwise, draw every other background with different colour.
      wxColour bgCol(245, 245, 255);
      dc.SetBrush(wxBrush(bgCol));
      dc.SetPen(wxPen(bgCol));
      dc.DrawRectangle(rect);
   }

   virtual wxCoord OnMeasureItem(size_t item) const
   {
      return 20;
   }

   virtual wxCoord OnMeasureItemWidth(size_t item) const
   {
       return 400;
   }
};
```

Unfortunately this font-combobox does not behave like a normal combobox:

- when jumping through the elements within a GUI, as soon as the FontStyleComboBox  should be focused, it is not highlighted
- at the point when it should be focused, when pressing the up/down arrows, it does not slide through the elements of the combobox but changes the focus to the previous/next GUI element (right as somebody would hit shift-tab/tab)

So...any idea what could be missing here? Do I have to add some focus/focus-lost handling in this class?

This happens with wxWidgets 3.1 / Windows.

Comment: what OS/wxWidgets version do you testing on?

Comment: @Igor as already stated in the question it is wxWidgets 3.1 on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: it was a problem of version 3.1 for Windows. With version 3.0/Linux it never occurred and since version 3.1.4 it is fixed for Windows too.